# Android studio Incorrect whitespace warning every new line

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ide, android-studio-electric-eel

Starting with Android Studio Electric Eel (problem still present in 2022.1.1 Patch 2) I'm experiencing a problem with formatting warnings.

- I have Incorrect formatting warnings enabled from the settings.
- Every time a add a new line, since the IDE adds an indentation that follows the previous line one, I see a warning:

[image]

If I remove the indentation at the start of the line, the warning disappears.

[image]

This isn't ideal, since the indentation is removed automatically by the IDE when the file is saved. So the warning shouldn't appear. In Android Studio versions before Electric Eel it always worked fine.

I already tried invalidating/resetting the cache and nothing changed.

Do you know if it's an IDE bug? or am I missing something?

Comment: That looks like a bug, nothing in wrong with the code and it is indented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i think it's what @ToxicFlame427 said. it looks there's an existing bug. im experiencing the same problem using Flaming 2022.22.01 | Patch 1

This bug from Google seems to be related to this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273454808

Comment: Unfortunately I personally opened that bug  But it seems that Google is ignoring it... The problem is super annoying 

Comment: if you are impacted, can you add a +1 to the bug? maybe it will help...